# Issues making calls to a gRPC service on GKE (Cloud Endpoints & ESP) from browser (grpc-web)

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, grpc-web

**Intro to the issue**
I have a gRPC service that is running in GKE. I'm using Cloud Endpoints and have an ESP (Extensible Service Proxy) in front of it that I want to use to handle authentication (JWT tokens).

This sounds like a really great way to integrate all these tools together, but for the past 2 days I haven't been able to get this working. I can connect and make calls perfectly when running locally, but going through the ESP has proven to be pretty difficult to setup.

*Note: I eventually want to open up an http2 port, but my focus right now is getting browser support so I'm just opening the http port*

**The K8s deployment and service config**
My service is running and working, and I am deploying it with this manifest

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: esp-grpc-environment
spec:
  ports:
  # Port that accepts gRPC and JSON/HTTP2 requests over HTTP.
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 9090
    protocol: TCP
    name: http2
  selector:
    app: esp-grpc-environment
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: esp-grpc-environment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: esp-grpc-environment
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: esp
        image: gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime:1.16.0
        args: [
          "--http_port=9090",
          "--service=environment.endpoints.olamai-d64a7.cloud.goog",
          "--rollout_strategy=managed",
          "--backend=grpc://127.0.0.1:8000",
          "--cors_preset=basic",
          "--cors_allow_headers=Keep-Alive,User-Agent,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Transfer-Encoding,X-Accept-Content-Transfer-Encoding,X-Accept-Response-Streaming,X-User-Agent,X-Grpc-Web,Grpc-Timeout,Authorization,authorization",
          "--cors_expose_headers=grpc-status,grpc-message,authorization"
        ]
        ports:
          - containerPort: 9090
      - name: environment
        image: terrariumai/environment:0.0.1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8000
```

So I was originally just using my own nginx proxy but decided I wanted the features of Endpoints. With this and a lot of errors, I got all of the Cors arguments for the ESP.

And here is the config with the auth settings

```yaml
type: google.api.Service
config_version: 3

name: environment.endpoints.<project id>.cloud.goog
title: Environment gRPC API

apis:
  - name: endpoints.terrariumai.environment.Environment

authentication:
  providers:
    - id: firebase
      jwks_uri: https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com
      issuer: https://securetoken.google.com/<project-id>
  rules:
    - selector: "*"
      requirements:
        - provider_id: firebase

usage:
  rules:
    - selector: endpoints.terrariumai.environment.Environment.CreateEntity
      allow_unregistered_calls: true
```

**Making calls to the service with Node/React**
So once this is running and deployed, I use my React app to hit the service like this

```js
import {
  CreateEntityRequest
} from "../api/environment_pb";

this.props.firebase
      .auth()
      .currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true)
      .then(function(idToken) {
        var service = new EnvironmentClient(addr, null, null);
        var request = new CreateEntityRequest();
        var metadata = {
          authorization: `Bearer ${idToken}`
        };
        console.log(idToken);
        service.createEntity(request, metadata, (err, resp) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Got error: ", err);
          }
          console.log("Resp: ", resp);
        });
      })
```

And from this, I get this error

```
POST http://<external-ip>/endpoints.terrariumai.environment.Environment/CreateEntity 403 (Forbidden)
```

But at this point I'm so confused. Here are the log from the ESP pod (which I'm having trouble reading)

```
[09/Jul/2019:20:40:49 +0000] "POST /endpoints.terrariumai.environment.Environment/CreateEntity HTTP/1.1" 403 210 "http://localhost:3000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
```

To me, it seems like the ESP is refusing the calls and saying they are forbidden (maybe not authenticated??). But at this point I'm stumped. I really don't know where to look further. I would appreciate any help and can provide any more information if it's necessary!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you were using a very old release of ESP. In your GKE deployment yaml file, you were using 1.16.0.  If you remove ".16.0",  with only "gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime:1",  it will pick up the latest ESP release which is 1.35.0 for now.

I can help you to debug it if you use the latest ESP with --enable_debug flag. The ESP debug log will be inside the ESP container in /var/log/nginx/error.log

Could you open an issue [here](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp)?  post debug log over there. Thanks.

Also post your service config too. ( you can get your service config by "gcloud endpoints configs describe")

Comment: Oh interesting, that was just the version the documentation used. I'll change it right now and open an issue over there.

Comment: Here is the issue I just opened up https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp/issues/640

Comment: I just found some information and added it to the issue I linked above. It looks like the JWT has the wrong audience, or the ESP is looking for the wrong audience. I'm not sure how to continue though as I don't think I fully understand the problem. If you are still willing to help I would appreciate it a ton! :)

Comment: You can set your own "audience" in the Service config. Here is the [instruction](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/authenticating-users) for Firebase